# Add Git buttons on the Toolbar in Android Studio (merge, rebase, new branch)

Tags: android-studio, toolbar

If you often create, merge, rebase, compare branches, you should know how to add icons from Main menu to the Toolbar. Sometimes clicking Git buttons is difficult inside menus, see screenshots.

[image]

Where is that "New branch" command inside a list of branches?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you should separate the Toolbar from Main menu, if it was not done before. `View > Appearance > Toolbar`.

[image]

Right-click on empty space in the Toolbar and press "Customize Menus and Toolbars...".

[image]

Expand "Main Toolbar" in the tree.

[image]

Scroll down and expand "MainToolBarSettings", "VCS Actions", click "Rollback", then in the top press "plus" and click "Add Action..." Here we will add new buttons.

[image]

In a window find "new branch". Select several commands with `Ctrl` click in Windows. Press "OK" and "OK".

[image]

Now you will see 3 new buttons in the Toolbar.

[image]